# How to export embedded data in Qualtrics?

Tags: javascript, html, qualtrics

Since I needed to customize my survey, I ended up using javascript to record most of my important responses. Firstly, if it's a "textarea" element that I'm using to record answers from the user, I am not able to save it as a response. So, I used Multiple Choice Question where each choice is populated by piping embedded data collected through textarea element. This way, I was able to see the answer as the recorded response. However, when I export is at CSV file, I don't get the data but just variable name ${e://Field/**input1**}.

I googled to see some examples that used *survey flow* to save the embedded data but in my case, these embedded data are generated dynamically in the process by the participants and setting value isn't possible in the survey flow.

Comment: Assuming you are correctly getting the data into embedded data using the JavaScript API then those embedded data fields should be exported with your data set. They are not in what you may expect the order to be though.

Comment: Actually, saving data from the survey flow screen did work for my case which saves data to a separate column. The only problem is it can't be dynamic and the variable needs to be set beforehand.

Comment: You can set the value of a known embedded data variable using JavaScript, you just can't dynamically create them without them already existing in the survey flow.